# Python: Parse list of 'key:value' elements to dictionary of 'key': value pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
['a:1', 'b:2', 'c:3', 'd:4']
```

I would like to convert to a ordered dict (using `collections`):

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

I have seen solutions using regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380992/get-python-dictionary-from-string-containing-key-value-pairs) but I am not familiar with regex enough to roll a solution. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: what about getting familiar with regex?

Comment: What does regular expressions have to do with this?

Comment: Been working on it... :)

Comment: See link in my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380992/get-python-dictionary-from-string-containing-key-value-pairs. Someone solved a similar problem using regex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
d = collections.OrderedDict(el.split(':') for el in your_list)
```

Or, converting the values to integers:

```
OrderedDict( (k, int(v)) for k, v in (el.split(':') for el in your_list))
```

Comment: This isn't quite right ... It appears the OP wants to have integers as values, but this will give strings ...

Answer (score 2):

To get the values as integers try something like:

```
In [67]: lis=['a:1', 'b:2', 'c:3', 'd:4']

In [68]: def func(x):
    spl=x.split(':')
    return spl[0],int(spl[1])
   ....: 

In [71]: dict(map(func,lis))
Out[71]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```