# extracting key value pairs from a string containing escaped characters

Tags: python, regex, escaping, key

this question builds on:
[get python dictionary from string containing key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380992/get-python-dictionary-from-string-containing-key-value-pairs)

I'd like to get key, value pairs with values that contain equals signs that are escaped out.

```
r = "key1=value1 key2=value2 request=http://www.pandora.com/json/music/artist/justin-moore?explicit\\=false uri=3DLoiRDsBABCAA9FvE1htRg\\=\\="
regex = re.compile(r"\b(\w+)=([^=]*)(?=\s\w+=\s*|$)")
d = dict(regex.findall(r))
print(d)

{'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

I cannot seem to get the values with escaped equals signs.  I'm pretty sure the ([^=]*) part is wrong.  I think I need to match on anything not containing the next key=

Answer (score 8):

Don't use a regular expression where string splitting will work:

```
dict(s.split('=', 1) for s in r.split())
```

Demo:

```
>>> r = "key1=value1 key2=value2 request=http://www.pandora.com/json/music/artist/justin-moore?explicit\\=false uri=3DLoiRDsBABCAA9FvE1htRg\\=\\="
>>> dict(s.split('=', 1) for s in r.split())
{'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1', 'request': 'http://www.pandora.com/json/music/artist/justin-moore?explicit\\=false', 'uri': '3DLoiRDsBABCAA9FvE1htRg\\=\\='}
```

This removes the need to escape `=` characters.

Comment: interesting.  works for the data I gave, but anything with spaces breaks.  For example:  key3=Web Log

Comment: @Jared: Sure, but then you should really use a proper parser anyway. For many such formats using a slightly adjusted [`shlex` parser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) will do wonders, provided you quote the value part. `key3="Web Log"` can easily be supported; that's how `supervisord` does it for example.

Comment: @Jared: see [the source of `dict_of_key_value_pairs()`](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/e4f3f0cad1697fdb76632dfe8a3935ae4540fbae/supervisor/datatypes.py#L80) for an example

Comment: ok great, thanks for the resources and your help on this issue.  You rock.

Answer (score 1):

got it.

```
regex = re.compile(r"\b(\w+)=(.*?)(?=\s\w+=\s*|$)")
```