# Regex find word including "-"

Tags: python, regex

I have the below regex (from this link: [get python dictionary from string containing key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380992/get-python-dictionary-from-string-containing-key-value-pairs))

```
r"\b(\w+)\s*:\s*([^:]*)(?=\s+\w+\s*:|$)"
```

Here is the explanation:

```
\b           # Start at a word boundary
(\w+)        # Match and capture a single word (1+ alnum characters)
\s*:\s*      # Match a colon, optionally surrounded by whitespace
([^:]*)      # Match any number of non-colon characters
(?=          # Make sure that we stop when the following can be matched:
 \s+\w+\s*:  #  the next dictionary key
|            # or
 $           #  the end of the string
)            # End of lookahead
```

My question is that when my string has the word with the "-" in between, for example: `movie-night`, the above regex is not working and I think it is due to the `b(\w+)`. How can I change this regex to work with word including the "-"? I have tried `b(\w+-)` but it does not work. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You may try 'b([\w-]+)'.

Comment: Where is the colon in your example? Your regex seems to require one, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something such as this:

```
r"\b([\w\-]+)\s*:\s*([^:]*)(?=\s+\w+\s*:|$)"
```

Note the `[\w\-]+`, which allows matching both a word character and a dash.

For readability in the future, you may also want to investigate [`re.X/re.VERBOSE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X), which can make regex more readable.

Comment: Best to escape the hyphen in case of future additions: ```[\w\-]+```